# Angular unit testcases for @ViewChildren QueryList

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test cases for view children query list, where I am looping to each element ref & taking width of item to check weather it will fit within div or not. So please tell me how to create a mock DOM for Querylist reference. Below is the code, span with reference #listEle is flex items

Test.component.html:

```
        <div #containerRef>
          <span *ngFor="let val of data| slice: 0:linksShown;" #listEle>
               <a href="val.link">{{ val.name }}</a>
          </span>
         </div>
```

Test.component.ts:

```
              import {
                      ElementRef,
                      OnInit,
                      QueryList,
                      ViewChild,
                      ViewChildren,
                  } from '@angular/core';

               @Component({
                           selector: 'app-test',
                           templateUrl: './test.component.html',
                           styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],
                         })
                export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
                @Input() data;
                @ViewChild('containerRef', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) containerRef: 
                ElementRef;
                listRef: QueryList<ElementRef>;
                @ViewChildren('listEle') set listEle(ref: QueryList<ElementRef>) {
                     this.listRef = ref;
                }
                linksShown: number;
                constructor() {}

                ngOnInit() {
                   let items = 0;
                   let count = 0;
                   this.listRef.toArray().forEach((ele) => {
                       count += ele.nativeElement.clientWidth;
                        if (count  < 
                         this.containerRef.nativeElement.clientWidth) {
                         count++;
                        }
                     });
                  this.linksShown = count;
                  }

                }
```

Test.component.spec.ts:

```
            import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
            import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from 
            '@angular/core/testing';
            import { TestComponent } from './host-links.component';

            describe('TestComponent', () => {
                let component: TestComponent;
                let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
            const data = [
                       {
                        name: 'test1',
                        link: '/test1',
                       },
                       {
                        parentName: 'test2',
                        link: '/test2',
                       }]

              beforeEach(async () => {
                 await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                 declarations: [TestComponent],
                 }).compileComponents();
              });

              beforeEach(() => {
                  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
                  component = fixture.componentInstance;
                  component.data = data;
                  fixture.detectChanges();
              });

                it('should get the linkShown count.', 
                 () => {
                   component.OnInit();
                   expect(component.linksShown).toEqual(2);
                });
             })
```